# Can any internet machine can use a SMTP Host

Tags: spring, sendmail

I have implemented mail sender functionality using spring and host details as follows

```
<property name="host" value="smtp.gmail.com" />
<property name="port" value="587" />
<property name="username" value="gmailid" />
<property name="password" value="password" />

<property name="javaMailProperties">
    <props>
        <prop key="mail.smtp.auth">true</prop>
        <prop key="mail.smtp.starttls.enable">true</prop>
    </props>
</property>
```

This is working fine but what i want to do is i don't want use smtp.gmail.com.. My windows machine has internet access can i use my machine as a host?..

If possible can you suggest some way how can i use my machine as mail server host.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can use your own machine for SMTP. There are several open source options available to you, depending on your OS - go have a look at [freshmeat.net](http://freshmeat.net) (Postfix would be my suggestion for a linux box).

You should however answer some questions for yourself first:

1. Why not use Google SMTP service - they do offer spam filtering, security and most of all - they are trusted by others.
2. Are you prepared and equipped to configure and run an SMTP server yourself? Do you know enough about securing your setup and troubleshooting when it doesn't work?

Cheers,

Answer (score 1):

While there is nothing preventing you *technically*, it depends a lot on what kind of emailing you are planning to do. If you are planning to do anything like mass-mailing, your mail-host would most likely be blacklisted fairly quickly as a spam-host. Today's larger mail-hosts are pretty aggressive in branding non-known hosts as spammers.